# Create filter in laravel API controller

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

Hi i want to create a filter to show mosque with event or activities only. Any idea to display the mosque with activities or events only ?. This one from back-end that later will be fetch using react

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Event;
use App\Mosque;
use App\Activity;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NotificationController extends Controller
{
    public function list()
    {
        $mosques = Mosque::get();

        $array = array();

        foreach ($mosques as $mosque) {
            array_push($array, [
                'mosque_name' => $mosque->name,
                'mosque_image'=> $mosque->image
            ]);
        }

        return $array;

        return response()->json(['result' => $mosques]);
    }

    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $mosque =  Mosque::find($request->mosque_id);
        $mosque->activities;
        $mosque->events;

        return response()->json(['result' => $mosque]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this

```
  public function show(Request $request)
      {
         $mosque =  Mosque::find($request->mosque_id);
          $mosque->activities;
           $mosque->events;
         return response()->json(['result' => $mosque->events ]);
      }
```

Comment: How is this answering the question?
The question is to display mosques with events or activities, all this does is assigning events as a result to the show page, not the mosque object, and it does not check if there are any activities or events.

Comment: $mosque =  Mosque::find($request->mosque_id)->whereHas('events')->orWhereHas('activities')->first();

Comment: @reylie please define relation in model in your application

Comment: @tarek taamali the relation in the model is the mosque has a many event and activity

Comment: @reylie are you try this $mosque = Mosque::find($request->mosque_id)->whereHas('events')->orWhereHas('activities')->get();

Comment: @tarek taamali actually i come out with                               
        $mosque = Mosque::find($request->mosque_id);
        $mosque->activities;
        $mosque->events;

     return response()->json(['result' => $mosque]);

Comment: @tareek taamalai it go direct because of the relationship so it will fetch all the activities and event with the mosque_id

Answer (score 1):

To filter rows from database, which has particular relationship, you can use `whereHas()` function on `QueryBuilder Instance`.

```
$mosques = Mosque::whereHas('events')
    ->orWhereHas('activities')
    ->get();
```

This function will only returns `mosques which has activities or events`, other `mosques` will not fetch.

Also if you only need the `name` and the `image` you can filter them too

```
$mosques = Mosque::whereHas('events')
    ->orWhereHas('activities')
    ->get(['name','image']);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, looking at the question asked.